# How to encapsulate starting unknown activities in Android?

Tags: android, oop, android-activity

I am trying to create a subclass of CardView that will be attached to a certain activity. The activity must have a Minigame interface implemented. If so the activity will set an on-click listener to start the new activity. However, Android Studio will not allow my parameter "activity" to call activity.class since it is not a class I have created.

````
        public GameCardView(@NonNull Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        public void addActivity(final AppCompatActivity activity) {
            if (activity instanceof Minigame) {
                super.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(this, activity.class);

                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

            } else {

                throw new NoMinigameInterfaceError("It looks like you did not implement" +
                        " the minigame interface in the activity attached to game card id: " + this.getId());
            }


        }

        private class NoMinigameInterfaceError extends Error {
            public NoMinigameInterfaceError(String errorMessage) {
                super(errorMessage);


            }

        }

    }```
````

Answer (score 0):

need to call **activity.getClass()**

Comment: I called it and android studio states Cannot resolve constructor